# Reporting Services 2008 - The user or group name 'xxx' is not recognized. (rsUnknownUserName)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I got a SSRS 2008 web edition instance (which was migrated from 2005 standard edition) and I need to change some security for a new folder I`ve just created.

When I go on report server web page (http://rsServerName.xyz/Reports), enter the new folder, go on folder properties, then when I click on **Security**, web page returns an error **The user or group name 'xxx' is not recognized. (rsUnknownUserName)**

I`ve checked the user in database - it exists, it has some items (reports) assigned to it, seems fine just like other users from database.

I first thought to just go into database and remove the entries from PolicyUserRole for users that aren't allowed into that folder, but there's also some info in SecData, and maybe some other places, and also found that microsoft doesn't support any queries against their reportserver database, so that might not be the brightest idea :)

Does anyone know any other way to remove the security from a specific folder ? Or maybe things to look at for this user name that it fails ? Another thing to mention, all security problems started when server was migrated from 2005 standard to 2008 web edition.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible way to fix this was to remove the user completely and add it back. During the migration described above several user's permissions were affected, and the only way to fix was to re-create them from scratch - not elegant, but worked.

Solution - find the user, remove, add back.